# jQuery not properly executing an ajax request

Tags: jquery

I've got another similar script running just fine, i don't see why this isn't working.  Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
$("#lastname").keyup(function(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(keyCode === 13) {
        passOnRegFront();
    }
    });
    $("#register").click(function() {
        passOnRegFront();
    });
function passOnRegFront() {
        var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
        var dataString = '&firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname;
        if(email=='' ||  password=='') {
            $('#success').fadeOut(400).hide();
            $('#error').fadeOut(400).show();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/home/passOnReg",
                data: dataString,
                json: {session_state: true},
                success: function(data) {
                if(data.registered == true) { // true means user is logged in.
                    $("#main1").hide();
                    $("#main1").load('<?=base_url()?>index.php/home/dashboard');
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there at least a request being send? If so is this request correct? What does it return?

Comment: Have you tested you get in the `else` part of your condition by doing an `alert()` or a `console.log()`. Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: Have you looked in the error console to see if there are any JS errors?  Have you stepped through it in the debugger to see which branches do and don't execute?  These are the basics of troubleshooting and then, if you're still stuck after that, you'd have a more specific question to ask.

Comment: check your view source for the url option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following problems jumped out at me as I skimmed through your code:

- The `email` and `password` variables are not defined, and from the context I would guess you probably intended `firstname` and `lastname` at that point. Copy and paste error from the other script you mention?
- There is an extra `});` at the end of the block. Maybe that is just the end of a `$(document).ready(function() {` that you don't show, but obviously I can't tell how much more code you have that isn't shown - for what you have shown this is an error.

As an aside, it would be easier to read and debug if you fixed the indenting: on first glance it appears that you are creating the `.click()` handler *inside* the `.keyup()` handler.

As another aside, the code would probably be clearer if you looked at using an object to set the `data` attribute of the [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. Get rid of `dataString` and just say:

```
...
data : { firstname : firstname, lastname : lastname },
...
```

(jQuery will create the appropriate query string for you as described in [the `.ajax()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).)